# said that it expect its jabs to work

Tags: grammar

The collocation "it expect" rather than "it expects" puzzled me.  Is "it exprect" correct? Should it be "it expects"?

> Biotech firm Moderna in Cambridge, Massachusetts, which has developed an RNA-based vaccine, has **said that it expect its jabs to work** against the UK variant and that tests are under way.

> Source: [Nature](https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-021-00031-0)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's asking about an obvious typo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is probably a typographic error.

The following two sentences are possible:

*Biotech firm Moderna ... has said that it expects its jabs to work*

or

*Biotech firm Moderna ... have said that they expect their jabs to work*